# repeat arange with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, repeat

I have an array with integer values.

```
a = [2,1,4,0,2]
```

I want a apply arange function to each value in a so as to have :

```
b = [0,1,0,0,1,2,3,1,2]
b "=" [arange(2),arange(1),arange(4),arange(0),arange(2)]
```

In fact I use a np.repeat function to repeat array rows according to array a, and I want to have a mark of i to linked each repeated value to the original one and to have an identification number to then distinguish them.

I tried with np.vectorize but with no success.

Comment: Could you show some more of your code - how exactly do you get from `a` to `b`? And most importantly, [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are definitely more numpythonic ways of doing things. One possibility could be something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def concatenated_ranges(ranges_list) :
    ranges_list = np.array(ranges_list, copy=False)
    base_range = np.arange(ranges_list.max())
    base_range =  as_strided(base_range,
                             shape=ranges_list.shape + base_range.shape,
                             strides=(0,) + base_range.strides)
    return base_range[base_range < ranges_list[:, None]]
```

If you are concatenating only a few ranges, then probably Mr. E's pure python solution is your best choice, but if you have even as few as a hundred ranges to concatenate, this stars being noticeably faster. For comparison I have used this two functions extracted from the other answers:

```
def junuxx(a) :
    b = np.array([], dtype=np.uint8)
    for x in a:
        b = np.append(b, np.arange(x))
    return b

def mr_e(a) :
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + range(y), a, [])
```

And here are some timings:

```
In [2]: a = [2, 1, 4, 0 ,2] # the OP's original example

In [3]: concatenated_ranges(a) # show it works!
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1])

In [4]: %timeit concatenated_ranges(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.6 us per loop

In [5]: %timeit junuxx(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 34 us per loop

In [6]: %timeit mr_e(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.58 us per loop

In [7]: a = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(10,))

In [8]: %timeit concatenated_ranges(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.1 us per loop

In [9]: %timeit junuxx(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 79.8 us per loop

In [10]: %timeit mr_e(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.82 us per loop

In [11]: a = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(100,))

In [12]: %timeit concatenated_ranges(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.4 us per loop

In [13]: %timeit junuxx(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 756 us per loop

In [14]: %timeit mr_e(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 149 us per loop

In [15]: a = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(1000,))

In [16]: %timeit concatenated_ranges(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 358 us per loop

In [17]: %timeit junuxx(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.38 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit mr_e(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.93 ms per loop
```

Comment: +1, I love answers with benchmarks! And I'll have to look into this `as_strided` function, it puzzles me.

Comment: @Junuxx It's one of those little numpy things that make it so irresistible. [These gists](https://gist.github.com/seberg) from numpy wiz [seberg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/455221/seberg) have some great examples of it at work.

Comment: Thank you very much. After reading that, I look [here](http://scipy-lectures.github.com/advanced/advanced_numpy/index.html) some documentation. It's very helpful and useful.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is similar to Junuxx - I am not sure the answer you gave for b is the one you want

```
a = [2, 1, 4, 0 ,2]
reduce(lambda x, y: x+range(y), a, [])
```

Gives me

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Another inconsistency is that the question title and tags mention Numpy, but the example shows lists. Your code would work on lists but not on Numpy arrays (plus on arrays does not do append but vector addition)

Comment: That is true. I thought that it mentioned `np.repeat` as it was close-ish to the desired behaviour, rather than being a numpy question specifically

Answer (score 1):

This does what you seem to be describing, i.e. a concatenation of aranges for all the values in `a`. Although it would mean there are some errors in the `b` you give:

```
>>> a = [2, 1, 4, 0, 2]
>>> b = np.array([], dtype=np.uint8)
>>>for x in a:
>>>    b = np.append(b, np.arange(x))
>>> print b
array([0,1,0,0,1,2,3,0,1,])
```

After your edit which explains you want a list of aranges, I think this would be more effective:

```
>>> a = [2, 1, 4, 0, 2]
>>> b = [np.arange(x) for x in a]
>>> print b
[array([0, 1]), array([0]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1])]
```

Comment: As I begin in Python, it's always good to have different solutions. It will help for future issues. I just mention the solution of Junuxx seems faster than Mr E's one.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that is more memory efficient in general, and is slightly faster:

```
import numpy as np
def concatenated_ranges2(ranges_list):
    cumsum = np.append(0, np.cumsum(ranges_list[:-1]))
    cumsum = np.repeat(cumsum, ranges_list)
    return np.arange(cumsum.shape[0]) - cumsum
```

Testing this function and the previous one:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(1000,))
>>> %timeit concatenated_ranges(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 142 us per loop
>>> %timeit concatenated_ranges2(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 72.6 us per loop
```